# Porque "24"<="7" = true?

Tags: javascript, operador

Alguien me puede explicar por que 24 es menor o igual a 7.

```
"24"<="7"
true
```

Pero si pongo "24"<="10" da falso???

```
"24"<="10"
false
```

Uso JavaScript y también C++, y en los 2 me da lo mismo.

Porque, el algo por los string?

Comment: Sencillo. Cómo comparas lógicamente dos cadenas?

Comment: El operador sigue el [orden lexográfico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_lexicogr%C3%A1fico)

Comment: Porque estas comparando strings, no números

Comment: Que bonita pregunta. Josué, qué te parece si investigas lo que los usuarios han comentado, y luego respondes tu propia pregunta. Sería maravilloso para los demás usuarios del sitio entender por qué sucede.

Comment: Definitivamente es una bella pregunta, leer sobre orden lexográfico te ayudará a entenderlo. Y apoyo la idea de Arriel de responder a tu propia pregunta una vez tengas la respuesta para que otros pueda entender lo que sucede.

Comment: Por la misma razon que las palabras que empiezan con A están antes en el diccionario que las que empiezan con B, mas alla de que una sea muy grande "ATARDECER" y la otra sea pequeña como "BI". Estas comparando posiciones alfabeticas basicamente, se compara el primer caracter de cada palabra. Que va primero, 2 o 7? Si son iguales se compara el caracter siguiente. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buen día

La explicación viene dada del valor de la posición que representa ese "string" en el Diccionario llamado Unicode (mejor conocido "Low Ascii"), por lo tanto, el orden en ese Diccionario u orden lexicográfico representa un número.

En Javascript hay una manera que conozcas ese valor y es mediante el método llamado `charCodeAt`:

Por ejemplo, si quieres saber por qué "a" minúscula es mayor a "A" mayúscula observa el resultado al momento de adquirir su valor según su posición en el orden del "Diccionario Unicode" mediante este código:

```
console.log("a".charCodeAt(0)) // el valor será 97
console.log("A".charCodeAt(0)) // el valor será 65
```

En tu caso, el string con dos caracteres o más solo toma el primer carácter de la izquierda para comparar y es por eso que "27" (el "2" vale 50) es menor que "7" que vale 55 y te da `true`.

... Y en el otro ejemplo que colocaste "24" (el "2" que vale 50) es mayor que "10" (el "1" vale 49) es por eso que te da `false`.

Para saber más de este Diccionario llamado Unicode visita el siguiente enlace https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Answer (score 0):

Porque estás comparando cadenas de caracteres, no enteros.

Si lo que quieres es hacer una comparación numérica, tienes que utilizar variables numéricas:

```
24<=7
```

O bien hacer una conversión:

```
parseInt("24")<=parseInt("7")
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque estás comparando Cadenas. No se toman 24, 7 y 10 como números sino como cojunto de caracteres (por las comillas en que lo pones). En Javascript cada caracter tiene un valor numérico. De modo que, en resumen, estás calculando los valores numéricos de cada uno de los caracteres que componenen las cadenas '24', '7' y '10', y por ello estás obteniendo True y False.

Si quieres comparar núḿeros:

24<=7 //False
24<=10 // False